# Data Structures and implementations, Why shouldn't I just use the data collection APIs?

Tags: java, data-structures

After a long online search on this very subject, I have not been able to find a suitable answer.

I am recent java learner and everyday I come across exciting things to learn. Recently, I have been learning data-structures and now understand the Big-O theory. I do understand the importance of knowing the data structures and their implementations whether it be a LinkedList or BST.

When working on real-world Java projects, is it a common practice to write data structures classes or use the JAVA data structures API offered by the SDK?

In an IDE, if I let say implement Java's native LinkedList, I can access all its native methods which makes things fast and easy.

I am certain there are instances when one might have a need to extend these classes to accommodate certain tasks.

Comment: Generally, most people use the Collections API, or implementations in the Apache or Google libraries, as it's simply quicker and an easier (and they tend to be tested). You'd have to have a particular edge case to start rolling your own - IMHO

Comment: If you're writing your own data structure implementation, either you have a dataset with certain magical properties that no existing data structure deals with as efficiently as you could (extremely unlikely), or you're just a terrible engineer that can't use available resources. I do see these types of questions in interviews often such as can you implement self balancing binary search tree. The next time I get asked one of these questions, I plan to pull up an implementation on wikipedia and copy verbatim.

Comment: You certainly would use them 9 times out of ten, probably much more, but it helps to know the basic data structures from first principles. At the least it will inform your choice among the built-in Collections.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your advice and input. I did take a data-structures class at a local community college, and it was waste of time. 

Once again thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linked list is a boring data structure. There are very few things you can do that will actually improve or extend one in any meaningful way. Once you start looking at more interesting data structures, like cache-oblivious search trees, or meldable heaps, or catenable deques, or 2-3 finger trees, you will likely find more potential to do interesting things if you study them very carefully, implement them (or parts of them) yourself, and become intimately familiar with their structures. Implementing things directly instead of using a public API just for the sake of doing it is unlikely to accomplish anything, but if you can see a way to do it *much better* that way, that's another story.

Comment: Thank you @dfeuer for your time and advice. I have not even heard of some of the mentioned data-structures in your reply however it gives me more to Google and learn. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you write your own data structures to group your data. You might use java collections in your classes and you might have java collections of your classes bu you wouldn't normally write your own collection classes.

e.g.

```
// pseudo code only
class Plane
{
    ...
    private string id;
    private string type;
    private List<Passengers> passengers;
    ...
}

...

List<Plane> fleet = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently using Eclipse and if I let say implement Java's native LinkedList, I can access all its native methods which makes things fast and easy.

In practice, it usually just makes it "fast and easy" to break your code.  Generally speaking, you should almost certainly only use the built-in Java collection types, because

- they've been optimized by lots of very smart people over a long time
- they're much better tested than anything you could write
- they're designed to keep you from accidentally breaking any of their internal implementation
- they let you maintain compatibility with other Java libraries that use collections

Writing your own low-level data structures is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Why should you have all the fun implementing interesting data structures?